# Remove rows with same column value from DataTable and add corresponding values

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, dataset, linq-to-dataset

I have a DataTable with multiple columns. If the value of certain column repeats, I need to remove that row and add the quantities against it. For example, following datatable

```
ITEM    QTY
------------
1       20
2       10
2       10
3       20
```

would become:

```
ITEM    QTY
-----------
1       20
2       20
3       20
```

This is what I did

```
var table = dt.AsEnumerable() 
.GroupBy(row => row.Field("ITEM")) 
.Select(group => group.First()) 
.CopyToDataTable();
```

It removes the extra row but doesn't add up the quantities. So please help me in this regard.

Comment: try this [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415519/best-way-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-data-table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Sum`. You just have to find the duplicate-rows first:

```
var dupGroups = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ITEM"))
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Now you can use them to get the sum and to remove the redundant rows from the table.

```
foreach (var group in dupGroups)
{
    DataRow first = group.First();
    int sum = group.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("QTY"));
    first.SetField("QTY", sum);
    foreach (DataRow row in group.Skip(1))
        dt.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Or in one query which creates a new `DataTable`.

```
DataTable newTable = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ITEM"))
    .Select(g => 
    {
        DataRow first = g.First();
        if (g.Count() > 1)
        {
            int sum = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("QTY"));
            first.SetField("QTY", sum);
        }
        return first;
    })
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

However, even the second approach  modifies the original table which might be undesired since you use `CopyToDatatable` to create a new `DataTable`.  You need to clone the original table(`DataTable newTable = dt.Clone();`) to get an empty table with the same schema. Then use `NewRow` + `ItemArray.Clone()` or `table.ImportRow` to create a real clone without modifying the original data.

See: [C# simple way to copy or clone a DataRow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025012/c-sharp-simple-way-to-copy-or-clone-a-datarow)

**Edit**: Here is an example how you can create a clone without touching the original table:

```
DataTable newTable = dt.Clone();
var itemGroups = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ITEM"));
foreach (var group in itemGroups)
{
    DataRow first = group.First();
    if (group.Count() == 1)
        newTable.ImportRow(first);
    else
    {
        DataRow clone = newTable.Rows.Add((object[])first.ItemArray.Clone());
        int qtySum = group.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("QTY"));
        clone.SetField("QTY", qtySum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. The second approach is helpful.

Comment: @Sara: But the second approach is the most "dangerous" since it modifies both tables in a subtle way. I would use the first if i don't want to create a new table and `table.Clone()` + `ImportRow` if i want to create a copy table with summed values.

Comment: @Sara: Added an example(untested) to show how you can create a clone with totalized  data without modifying the original table.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I used your second approach and tested it. It seems to me that original table remains the same. At least the number of rows remains the same. I didn't understand the subtle way in which original table gets modified.

Comment: @Sara: The "subtle way in which original table gets modified" on my second approach (or Cuong Le's) is at `first.SetField("QTY", sum);`. This updates an existing `DataRow` instance of the original table, so the data gets changed. So you are ending with the same amount of rows but with totalized data on one `DataRow`. The `CopyToDataTable` at the end creates a new `DataTable` and copies all rows into it. However, the old table is now "corrupted". My first approach is more clear since it modifies only the original table and don't create a new one. Btw, consider to accept an answer :)

Comment: Ok great. Got it now :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var table = dt.AsEnumerable() 
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ITEM")) 
    .Select(group => {
        var row = group.First();
        row['QTY'] = group.Sum(x => x.Field<int>('QTY'));
        return row;
    }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: However, this modifies the original table which might be undesired since OP uses `CopyToDatatable` to create a new `DataTable`. Btw, the same problem has [my second approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18463169/284240). You need to clone the original table and use `NewRow` + `ItemArray.Clone()` or `table.ImportRow` to create a real clone without modifying the original data.

Comment: @Cuong Le Thanks. It works. It modifies the original but that is the minor issue.

Answer (score 1):

This won't change your original `DataTable`:

```
var table = dt.Copy().AsEnumerable()
                      .GroupBy(row=>row["ITEM"])
                      .Select(g=> {
                                DataRow dr = g.First();
                                dr.SetField("QTY", g.Sum(x=>x.Field<int>("QTY")));
                                return dr;
                             })
                      .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: You also don't use `dr` anywhere

Comment: @musefan thanks, I don't know why I typed it wrongly. That would be `dr`.