# Insert datarow from one datatable to a particular index

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datarow

I'm retrieving `DataTables` from my database and I need to insert a particular row from one `DataTable` into a determined index into another `DataTable`.

basically I would like to have say, row[0] of `DataTable` dt1 inserted into `DataTable` dt2 at index 4.

These are two different tables obtained from two different database calls.  Is there a way to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[EDIT]
Sorry, Here's what I've done

```
DataTable dt1 = populateTable();
DataTable targetTable = populateTargetTable();
DataRow dr;
dr = dt1.NewRow();
dr = targetTable.Rows[0];

int index=0;
DataRow temp;
for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    temp = dt1.Rows[i];
    if (rowFitsCondition(temp)){
        index = i;
    }
}
dt1.Rows.InsertAt(dr, index);
```

and the `InsertAt()` call fails, and gives me the `This row already belongs to another table error.`

Comment: This seems like a non-issue.  Read the data from one table insert it into another table -- standard ETL stuff.  What exactly is your question, why can't you just write the code?

Comment: is these both datatable have same schema?

Comment: Have you tried any thing?

Comment: And what does not work?

Comment: @StingyJack the `InsertAt()` call fails, and gives me the `This row already belongs to another table` error.

Comment: @StingyJack that link suggests the `ImportRow()` which doesn't allow for an insert to a specific index.  If that's really the only way to do it I guess I'll have to create a temp `DataTable` to import the rows from the `dt1` and once I reach the particular index then import the row from the `targetTable` and afterwards continue importing the remaining rows from `dt1`

Comment: Please read the rest of the first answer, but it seems odd to worry about index order in a data table. Typically you would use a DataView to determine how to display data, and .Select() to choose rows from the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with `Clone`

```
dr= dt1.NewRow();
dr.ItemArray = targetTable.Rows[0].ItemArray.Clone() as object[]; 
dt1.Rows.InsertAt(dr, index);
```

Comment: This ended up being just what I needed!  Thank you!

Comment: @shadonar - This is the second part of the answer I marked this question as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

The row exists as part of the source table. You need to create a new row in the target table and copy the relevant values from the source to the target row, then add the target row to the target table.

This linked [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12025012/16391) has a few ways to accomplish this.