# ImportRow make the new row column missing

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I want to copy all rows in old datatable (`oldDT`) to a new datatable (`dt`) using `ImportRow` method. But the new row doesn't have a same column with the old one. Here is my code:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in oldDT.Rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dr["tenant_no"].ToString()); //giving a correct result
    dt.ImportRow(dr);
    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0]["tenant_no"].ToString()); //giving an error Column 'tenant_no' does not belong to table .
}
```

i try to use the answer [C# simple way to copy or clone a DataRow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025012/c-sharp-simple-way-to-copy-or-clone-a-datarow/12025072#12025072) and here is my new code:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in oldDT.Rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dr["tenant_no"].ToString());
    DataRow newDR = oldDT.NewRow();
    newDR.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray.Clone() as object[];
    dt.Rows.Add(newDR); //giving an error "This row already belongs to another table."
    MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[0]["tenant_no"].ToString());
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... this will work

```
 DataTable dt= new DataTable();
   dt= oldDT.Clone();
    for (int i=0;i < oldDT.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.ImportRow(dataTable.Rows[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DataTable.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if you are not locked into using the `ImportRow` :

> Copies both the structure and data for this DataTable.

```
DataTable dt = oldDt.Copy();
```

Comment: actually, i want to join more than 1 old table into one. so i think this can't be used.

Comment: @Kuro13 Ok, sorry didn't know that.  Does it work if you just use `NewDataTable.Rows.Add(drfromoldtable);` ?

Comment: it will giving an error "row is already belong to another table" because as far as i know, a row can only belong to 1 table.

Comment: @Kuro13 ah yes that pesky error. Maybe this answer could help you, if you have not tried this already.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12025072/1483002

Comment: finally i use 'datatable.clone()' to clone just the schema and it works.
thanks..