# How to copy rows from a DataTable to another DataTable WITHOUT deleting existing rows?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, ado.net

How can I copy rows from one DataTable to another? Using `DataTable.Copy()` is not an option since this creates a NEW DataTable and deletes any existing DataRows. What I'm trying to do is add rows in a `List<DataTable>` to another table. Is there some method available that is able to do this?  Or is iterating through all tables and rows and calling `DataTable.ImportRow()` my only option?

[UPDATE]
Ok, this is the full scenario. I have a DataTable with 2 million+ records. Loading it throws `System.OutOfMemoryException`. So, I decided I need to page/batch load it. I'm creating the destination table using `DataAdapter.FillSchema()` for the purpose of loading only the columns. After that, I get the 'full records' using `DataAdapter.Fill()` (another DataTable), then split it into a `List<DataTable>`. When using `DataTable.Merge`, this exception is thrown: "Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."

Comment: Have you looked at DataTable.Merge or DataTable.Load?

Comment: DataTable.Load is not what I'm looking for since what I need to pass is a DataTable object and not IDataReader. On the other hand, when i use DataTable.Merge, an error 'Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.' is thrown. Additional note: the destination DataTable is created using DataAdapter.FillSchema. That's why I don't understand why it would throw an error like this.

Comment: As far as i know ImportRow is the only option.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025012/c-sharp-simple-way-to-copy-or-clone-a-datarow

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/08/copy-add-rows-from-one-datatable-to-another-datatable.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried merge as Michael said with the following code and its working for me.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name");
table.Columns.Add("Address");

table.Rows.Add("Shan", "ADC Street");

DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
table2.Columns.Add("Name");
table2.Columns.Add("Address");
table2.Rows.Add("Raj", "EFG Street");

table2.Merge(table,true);

Console.WriteLine(table2.Rows.Count);      //2
Console.WriteLine(table2.Rows[0]["Name"]); //Raj
Console.WriteLine(table2.Rows[1]["Name"]); //Shan
```