# Copy a DataRow with an extra column

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I'm trying to add a new column to an already existing DataTable using c#.

The best I could do is to actually copy each `DataRow` as explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025012/c-sharp-simple-way-to-copy-or-clone-a-datarow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020270/copy-rows-from-datatable-to-another-datatable-c-sharp) but with no success since those answers specifically say that both `DataTable` must have the same columns. Whenever I try to add any kind of value to the new column (which is at the end of a new DataTable named `dt` I'm left with a DataTable with the same number of rows but no values at all.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ret.Rows)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray, "1");
}
```

`ret` is a DataTable with X columns and N Rows.

`dt` is a DataTable with X+1 columns and N Rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as desired:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ret.Rows)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
    for (int i = 0; i < dr.ItemArray.Length; i++)
        row.SetField(i, dr.ItemArray[i]);
    row.SetField(dt.Columns.Count - 1, "1");
}
```

Another approach is to assign a [`DefaultValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) to the last column since you're using always the same constant value:

```
dt.Columns[dt.Columns.Count - 1].DefaultValue = "1";
```

Now you don't need to provide this value. You can use [`DataTable.Merge`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
dt.Merge(ret);
```

Comment: yep. That did it. I'm a little worried about the performance I might get but It works. Thanks!

Comment: @MiquelColl: performance is not an issue. All .NET methods like `DataTable.ImportRow` use similar loops but with additional overhead.

Comment: @MiquelColl: but there was a bug, i used `dr.SetField` instead of `row.SetField`. I've also provided another approach.

Comment: I used the first code you provided row[i] which worked as well. Any difference with the setField?

Comment: There's no Default Value, I was just putting a 1 in there in order to reduce the complexity of the question. Thanks regardless!

Comment: @MiquelColl: ok, maybe it's helpful for others. `SetField` is a similar way to the indexer but it comes into handy with nullable types.