# Filter Data table to list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
DataTable dttoexcel=some data source;
String[] pro = { "Az","Bz","X" };

for (int f = 0; f < pro.Length; f++)
{
    var LoginDetails = dttoexcel.Rows
                       .Cast<DataRow>()
                       .Where((r => r.Field<string>("Subcategoryname") == pro[f]))
                       .ToList();
}
```

Every time the list is updated with new data, the old data will be overwritten.I want to store all the data into list without loosing old data.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: your question is unclear to me. I don't see anything in your code snippet that's replacing the list, or modifying any list at all. it's simply just creating a new one which you set to the LoginDetails variable

Answer (score 0):

With every iteration you are creating new `LoginDetails` object, so you need to store your filtered data somewhere, for example in the same type `List` using `AddRange` or `Concat` methods. You can try something like this:

```
 DataTable dttoexcel = some data source;
 String[] pro = { "Az", "Bz", "X" };
 List<DataRow> loginDetails = new List<DataRow>();
 for (int f = 0; f < pro.Length; f++)
 {
     loginDetails.AddRange(dttoexcel //or Concat method
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Where((r => r.Field<string>("Subcategoryname") == pro[f]))
         .ToList());
 }
```

`AddRange` and `Concat` methods have different semantics:

**`AddRange`** - modifies source list by adding items to it.

**`Concat`** - returning the source list, with added new items, without modifying the source list.

---

### Update

To create new `DataTable` with filtered results, simply do this:

```
DataTable filteredTable = new DataTable();
filteredTable = loginDetails.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Its working ,but How to map this list to a new datatable ?SeM

Comment: Take a look to an "Update" section.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataTable dttoexcel=some data source;
    String[] pro = { "Az","Bz","X" };
    List<dynamic> LoginDetails = new List<dynamic>();
    for (int f = 0; f < pro.Length; f++)
    {

         LoginDetails.AddRange(dttoexcel.Rows
                     .Cast<DataRow>()
                     .Where((r => r.Field<string>("Subcategoryname") == 
          pro[f])).ToList());

    }
```

Comment: Don´t use `List<dynamic>` when the type of the elements is known at compile-time?

Comment: Actually it is a more flexible approach and the type is automatically converted to the input type meaning all attributes, classes and methods are inherited, more simply put, the type is only then defined when data is passed to the variable

Comment: Well, you don´t *need* the flexibility, but instead loose strong typing which may lead to tyoing-errors. E.g. when you write `myList[0].myMember` instead of `myList[0].MyMember` compiler won´t complain. Instead you get a runtime-exception. If we don´t wanted strong typing we could use any scripting language such as JavaScript.

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with the defined type, how are typing mistakes a consequence of the defined type, Intellisense itself detects the type (not even at runtime) and provides the same suggestions you would get for the exact type itself. You can't even use methods or classes that are outside the bounds of your desired type. Basically, you are actually dealing with your desired type and also reducing room for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Every time your loop executes or iterates, it declares a new variable on this line:

```
var LoginDetails = ....
```

Instead, you need to concat your result so that your data will not be overwritten everytime you iterate on your loop:

```
List<DataRow> LoginDetails = new List<DataRow>(); //Replace T with your entity
for (int f = 0; f < pro.Length; f++)
    {
        LoginDetails = LoginDetails.Concat(dttoexcel.Rows
                     .Cast<DataRow>()
                     .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Subcategoryname") == 
                      pro[f]).ToList()).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copying `DataRow` references to `List` won't prevent overriding their content. So one should clone existing `DataRow` objects (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025012/c-sharp-simple-way-to-copy-or-clone-a-datarow) for details). Also you can use `HashSet` to improve filtering:

```
DataTable dttoexcel = null;
string[] pro = { "Az", "Bz", "X" };
var proSet = new HashSet<string>(pro);

// Storage for copied data. Copy metadata from the original table
DataTable dttoexcelOld = dttoexcel.Clone();

foreach (var row in dttoexcel.Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Where(r => proSet.Contains(r.Field<string>("Subcategoryname"))))
    // Clone the row to prevent further overwriting and add it to dttoexcelOld table
    dttoexcelOld.ImportRow(row);
```

Comment: stop-cran ,this is what exactly i need ,Thanks for your help